# YouTube API v3 - Determine if a user has watched a video?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a google apps script which (among other things) needs remove watched videos from YouTube playlists using the YouTube API (v3).

I tried getting the watch history with `YouTube.playlistItems.list();` but since a recent update to the API (September 2016) watch history is no longer available through the API.

Is there any other way to determine if a user has watched a specific video or not through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. There was an open issue, but it was closed "WontFix"

> https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin features , but you can get the time of watching duration by using the Event logs, EventId -1 is Start and EventId 0 is Finish, if duration is same or above assume to be has watched completely :P

EventId is a part of Youtube API

Comment: Could you provide some links? I can't find anything about youtube events on the google api documentation.